# PHP - TCP/IP fsockopen

Tags: php, tcp

I was wondering if anyone has had any experience with this before. I'm trying to write a simple script that will continously read data from the TCP/IP stream but for some reason or another the script reads in a bunch of data, writes it out and then just stops.

```
$fp = fsockopen("xxxx", 3000, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128)."\n";
        fflush($fp);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I'd like it to have a constant flow to it, rather then echo out a bunch of data then wait 30 seconds and output a bunch more data. Anyone have any ideas?

---- EDIT ----

ZMQ Code

```
include 'zmsg.php';

$context = new ZMQContext();
$client = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_DEALER);

// Generate printable identity for the client
$identity = sprintf ("%04X", rand(0, 0x10000));
$client->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_IDENTITY, $identity);
$client->connect("tcp://xxxx:3000");

$read = $write = array();
$poll = new ZMQPoll();
$poll->add($client, ZMQ::POLL_IN);

$request_nbr = 0;
while (true) {
    // Tick once per second, pulling in arriving messages
    for ($centitick = 0; $centitick < 100; $centitick++) {
        $events = $poll->poll($read, $write, 1000);
        $zmsg = new Zmsg($client);
        if ($events) {
            $zmsg->recv();
            echo $zmsg->body()."\n";
            //printf ("%s: %s%s", $identity, $zmsg->body(), PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
    $zmsg = new Zmsg($client);
    //$zmsg->body_fmt("request #%d", ++$request_nbr)->send();
}
```

Comment: Your need to put it in an infinite loop of sorts though a better solution would be to make a server daemon that restarts after its finished. Dont access the result from the running script put is somewhere else it can be read using another thread/connection, else your get some blocking.

Comment: Are there any good examples I can see this?

Comment: do you see FALSE being printed?  If so, it's the fgets function that encountered an error.  Most likely, your feof is returning false at some point and the while loop exits.  This can be a bug from client side (your client is closing the connection) or an architectural problem.  In your case, I would consider using [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/) (libs available in pretty much every language including PHP)

Comment: @Phil I've tried using ZMQ but it doesn't read the data at all. It just hangs

Comment: Care to show your code ?  It shouldn't hang if used properly.

Comment: @Phil Edited my question for you

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with ZMQ.  I see a dealer that seems to face client side?  If the sole purpose is to read stream and print it, I'll show you a script that'll do it.  For exemple, no need to poll every second, the operation is blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you connect to a server (as a client) if your goal is ONLY to PULL data (read).

```
<?php
$context = new ZMQContext();
$sock = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$sock->connect("tcp://ADDRESS:3000");

while (true)
{
    $request = $sock->recv(); # recv is blocking by default, no need to put timers.
    printf ("Received: %s;%s", $request, PHP_EOL);
}
?>
```

if you want to reply, you'll need to use a pair socket (ZMQ::SOCKET_PAIR), then you can use:

```
$sock->send("data to send");
```

Also, if instead of you connecting to clients, clients connects to you, use the bind method instead of connect.

EDIT:  use the PUSH socket type on the other side if you use the pull here, else, use the pair socket on both sides.

Comment: Thanks! WOrked like a charm